# Kentico Sharepoint Connector: Support of Sharepoint document sets

Tags: sharepoint, kentico, connector, document-set

I'm having trouble fetching data of my Sharepoint online & on-premise environments using the Kentico Sharepoint connector.

I would like to fetch data from a document library with 'Document sets' in it.
Need access to 'rights, metadata, content inside document set'

Do any of you have any information that can help me?
Is Document sets supported by Kentico Connector?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what version of Kentico you're working with but typically it only includes:

- lists
- pictures
- file content